# Does the checkout dialog of the Stripe API allow descriptions more complex than strings?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

When using the Stripe checkout dialog, is it possible to set a description that's more complex than a just a plain string. I tried using a HTML element as the source of the description, but that doesn't seem to work, and HTML tags in the string (like line breaks or bold) are not interpreted.

So, in the JS:

```
handler.open({
    name: 'My App',
    description: 'Some description...', // getElementById('desc') does not work
    amount: 2000
});
```

This would save me some hassle because I could embed a proper summary of the items about to be bought in the checkout dialog, as opposed to having to show the summary somewhere else before the checkout dialog is exposed.

Comment: You might be able to do `document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML`, although you might want to use `.innerText` if the Stripe API doesn't allow HTML

Comment: Well, it's not that I want the convenience of pulling the text from my HTML file. I'll be generating the description in JS anyway, but I'd like to be able to format it properly. It looks like Stripe doesn't accept HTML in the string e.g. "Some <b>description</b> with a <br/>line break" is printed literally. I haven't found anything in the docs, but I was wondering if I've just missed something somewhere?

Comment: @downvoter you could at least tell me why

Comment: Probably because you can write code to construct whatever string you want and use that for the description.

Comment: @NateS what do you mean? It's not the text of the description i'm asking about. It's whether or not the Stripe API lets you somehow use HTML for the desc instead of plain text. Anyway, my guess is no.

Comment: Ah, yeah I didn't get that from your question title or code snippet. It's a string so at the very least you'd need to pass string containing HTML, not an HTML element. No need to guess either, if it renders the HTML as plain text then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with Stipe Support, and this feature is still not supported at the moment.

> We don't see this being possible to do with Stripe Checkout. We can't
> guarantee that this feature will be implemented at the moment, but
> we’re rapidly evolving our product suites, so be sure to stay close to
> hear about new products and features as we announce them.